# How to allow Xowa run in web browser(offline)

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I would like to setup Xowa(offline Wikipedia) in browser, but I would like to know how do I able to do so? I've google but doesn't seems to find any way to do so(or maybe I missed it).I able to import everything in my local and it works but is there any chance I can setup and run it in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do it in Kiwix instead of XOWA and work without issue even if multiple users uses it in the same time, is just that you have to download the dictionary based on your need and update the dictionary if there are any new updates.

Answer (score 0):

I able to run the Xowa in browser now by run

```
java -jar /xowa/xowa_linux.jar --app_mode http_server --http_server_port 8080
```

then open it browser however it seems like it only allow one user at one time and not allow multiple user to use it at the same time.